# Body wider than 100% only on mobile

Tags: html, css

I've looked everywhere for a reasonable answer to this, but I can't find it.  I have a relatively simple responsive [website](http://www.jordanhurt.com) and it works fine on every screen, except for below 768px.  For some reason, the body gets stretched and I get some horizontal scrolling, despite everything being set to 100%.  The body is the only portion that appears to be wider than the viewport.  I have a typical reset stylesheet to clear all padding and margins. I didn't forget to set meta name="viewport" tags or initial-scale.  I honestly have no idea what is going on. The layout is fine on a tablet. It is even correct if I turn my phone to landscape.  It's only in portrait that the body gets stretched about 15px outside the viewport and I have some horizontal scrolling. There is just blank white space on the right.  You can check out the link on your phone to see the issue firsthand. Any ideas on how to fix this?

The layout is pretty simple

```
<body>
  <div data-ng-include="'app/layout/shell.html'">
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the shell

```
<header class="fixed-header-shell" data-ng-include="'app/layout/topnav.html'"></header>
<div class="sections-shell" data-ng-view></div>
<footer class="footer-shell" data-ng-include="'app/layout/footer.html'"></footer>
```

All of the shell's are set to 100% width and have no right or left padding.  Here is the entire page css for reference.

```
@import "colors";
@import "fonts";
@import "reset";
@import "init";


/***********************
        Variables
************************/
/*Header*/
@defaultHeaderHeight:        110px;
@defaultNavHeight:           50px;
@defaultHeaderPadding:       @defaultHeaderHeight/2 - @defaultNavHeight/2;
@defaultHeaderSidePadding:   5.0%;

/*Footer*/
@defaultFooterHeight:        70px;

/*Section*/
@defaultSectionPadding:      60px;
//@defaultSidePadding:       5.0%;
@defaultSidePadding:         0px;
@defaultSectionHeaderMargin: 35px;
@mediumSidePadding:          2.5%;
@smallSidePadding:           1.5%;
@sectionShellWidth:          100%;
@defaultSectionWidth:        55%;


/***********************
        Mixins
************************/

.Clickable 
{
    &:hover 
    {
        text-decoration:none;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: @primaryAccent;
    }
    &:visited 
    {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    &:active 
    {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    &:link 
    {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
}

.Button
{
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: @divider;
    color: @primaryDark;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.Image(@imageURL, @radius, @size) 
{
    background-image: url(@imageURL);
    -webkit-border-radius:@radius;
       -moz-border-radius:@radius;
            border-radius:@radius;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: @size @size;
    width: @size;
    height: @size;
}

/***********************
        Body
************************/

body 
{
    background-color: @primaryBackground;
    width: 100%;
}


/***********************
        Shells
************************/

.fixed-header-shell 
{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: @primaryBackgroundDark;
}

.sections-shell
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: @defaultHeaderHeight;
    min-height: 900px;
    background-color: @primaryBackground;
}

.footer-shell
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: @primaryBackgroundDark;
}

/***********************
        Blocks
************************/

.fixed-header-block 
{
    background-color: @primaryBackgroundDark;
    height: @defaultHeaderHeight;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    //padding-left: @defaultHeaderSidePadding;
    //padding-right: @defaultHeaderSidePadding;
}

.section-block
{
    background-color: @primaryBackground;
    width: @defaultSectionWidth;
    padding-top: @defaultSectionPadding;
    padding-bottom: @defaultSectionPadding;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1.5px;
    border-bottom-color: @divider;

}

.footer-block 
{
    background-color: @primaryBackgroundDark;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: @defaultSectionPadding;
    padding-bottom: @defaultSectionPadding;
    height: @defaultFooterHeight;
}



/***********************
        Header
************************/

.fixed-header-logo 
{
    .HeadingLogo;
    .Clickable;
    height: @defaultHeaderHeight;
    line-height: @defaultHeaderHeight;
    //margin-left: @defaultHeaderSidePadding;
    text-align: left;
    color: @white;
}

.fixed-header-nav 
{
    height: @defaultHeaderHeight;
    //margin-right: @defaultHeaderSidePadding;
    text-align: right;
}

.fixed-header-nav-link 
{
    .Clickable;
    .HeadingLink;
    line-height: @defaultHeaderHeight;
    margin-left: 18px;
    //margin-right: 9px;
    color: @white;
}

/***********************
        Footer
************************/

.footer-link
{
    .Clickable;
    text-align: center; 
    .fa
    {
        .Clickable;
        color: @secondaryTextWhite;
        width: 5em;
        line-height: @defaultFooterHeight / 2;
    }
}

.footer-text
{
    .FooterText;
    color: @secondaryTextWhite;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: @defaultFooterHeight / 2;
    width: 24em;
}


/***********************
        Sections
************************/

.section-block-text
{
    .BodyText;
    color: @text;
    margin-top: @defaultSectionHeaderMargin;
}

.section-header
{
    .SectionHeader;
    text-align: left;
    color: @text;
}

.section-sub-header
{
    .SectionSubHeader;
    margin-top: @defaultSectionHeaderMargin / 2;
    color: @text;
}


/***********************
        Columns
************************/

.col
{
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.span_2_of_2
{
    width: 100%; 
}
.span_1_of_2
{
    width: 50%;
}



/***********************
        Grouping
************************/

.group:before,
.group:after 
{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.group:after 
{
    clear:both;
}

.group
{
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ 
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}


/***********************
        Intro
************************/

#intro 
{
    background-color: @primaryBackgroundDark;
    text-align: center;
    .section-block 
    {
        border-style: none;
        background-color: @primaryBackgroundDark;
    }

}

#intro-avatar 
{
    .Image("../../content/images/profile2.png", 9999px, 200px);
    margin: auto;
}

#intro-tagline 
{
    .HeadingTagline;
    color: @white;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}


/***********************
        Posts
************************/

#details
{
    border-style: none;
}

.post-link
{
    .Clickable;
}

.post-date
{
    text-align: left;
    color: @secondaryText;
    .PostDate
}

.post-title
{
    .PostTitle;
    .Clickable;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: @text;
}

.post-full-title
{
    .PostTitle;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: @text;
}

.post-text
{
    .BodyText;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: @text;
}

.post-full-text
{
    .BodyText;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    color: @text;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1.5px;
    border-bottom-color: @divider;
}

.post-navigation
{
    .Clickable;
    .Button;
    .BodyText;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
}


/***********************
        Projects
************************/

.project-section
{
    text-align: left;
}

.project-title
{
    .PostTitle;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: @text;
}

.project-text
{
    .BodyText;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    color: @text;
}

.project-image
{
    width: 100%;
    //height: 450px;
    border-color: @primaryLight;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: center;
}

.project-link
{
    .Clickable;
}

/***********************
        Contact
************************/

#contact
{
    .fa
    {
        color:@primaryAccent;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 24px;
    }
}


/***********************
        Links
************************/

#links
{
    background-color: @primaryBackgroundOff;

    h3
    {
        color:@primaryDark;
    }

    a
    {
        .Clickable;
        color: @primaryDark;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #facebook
    {
        .Image("../../content/images/facebook.png", 9999px, 75px);
        margin: auto;
    }

    #linkedin
    {
        .Image("../../content/images/linkedin.png", 9999px, 75px);
        margin: auto;
    }

    #google
    {
        .Image("../../content/images/google.png", 9999px, 75px);
        margin: auto;
    }

    #github
    {
        .Image("../../content/images/github.png", 9999px, 75px);
        margin: auto;
    }
}

.resume-link
{
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    .Clickable;
    .Button;
    .BodyText;
    display: inline-block;
}



/***********************
        Media Queries
************************/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
{
    .fixed-header-block
    {
        //padding-right: @mediumSidePadding;
        //padding-left: @mediumSidePadding;
    }

    .section-block
    {
        //padding-right: @mediumSidePadding;
        //padding-left: @mediumSidePadding;
        width: 70%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
{
    .fixed-header-shell 
    {
        position: relative;
    }

    .fixed-header-nav
    {
        text-align: center;
        height: @defaultHeaderHeight / 3;
    }

    .fixed-header-nav-link
    {
        line-height: @defaultHeaderHeight / 3;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .fixed-header-logo
    {
        text-align: center;
        line-height: @defaultHeaderHeight * 2 / 3;
        height: @defaultHeaderHeight * 2 / 3;
    }


    .fixed-header-block
    {
        //padding-right: @smallSidePadding;
        //padding-left: @smallSidePadding;
    }

    .sections-shell
    {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .section-block
    {
        //padding-right: @smallSidePadding;
        //padding-left: @smallSidePadding;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .col
    { 
        margin: 0 0 0 0%;
    }

    .span_2_of_2, 
    .span_1_of_2, 
    {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #intro-tagline 
    {
        font-size: 3.4em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    #intro-tagline
    {
        font-size: 3em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on iPhone? If yes, have you had a look at the css rendered on your phone via safari developer tools? They are invaluable for tracking down css issues on phone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have an android phone and tablet to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a fixed width of 24em on your `.footer-text`

Remove that and you will be good.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. I'll accept this answer when it lets me.